# Откуда берется эта переменная

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

В Spring у меня есть страница contact.jsp есть такая проврека переменной 

откуда она берет эту переменную contactList, 
в контроллере есть такой код.

```
@RequestMapping("/contact")
public String listContacts(Map<String, Object> map) {

    map.put("contact", new Contact());
    map.put("contactList", contactService.listContact());

    return "contact";
}
```

кто  ему передеает в качестве параметра map и как она его возвращает в jsp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

map(модель) приходит параметром при обработке запроса. Spring позволяет разные варианты для параметров функции использовать. Возвращать так же позволяет разные варианты, в данном случай возвращает имя View. А модель по идеи приходит по ссылке, заполняется и может использоваться дальше во View.
Подробнее тут можно почитать, если с английским хорошо - http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html

Comment: А по каким названиям можно получать эти названия, в данном случае название переменной "map"

Comment: Модель в обработчике должна быть Model ( http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/ui/ModelMap.html ). В модели имеется метод addAttribute, который позволяет складывать значения по имени. Или можешь вернуть ModelAndView. И в дальнейшем при рендеринге во вью, данные доступны по именам которые использовались для вложения.

Comment: понятно. Спасибо

Comment: а вот здесь что возвращается ${sessionScope["SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION"].message} что это за модель и что надо писать в квадратных скобках